# Xamarin.iOS change view controller in code

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

For my program, once an alert is is displayed, depending on the response of the alert, it will load a new view controller. I've tried doing this through code as the alert triggers a function/method depending on which button in pressed, however [this is the error message I get at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omUeJ.png) from main.cs. Here is the code I have in the function/method:

```
    void Alert_No()
    {
        UIStoryboard board = UIStoryboard.FromName("MainStoryboard", null);
        VCCoreSubjects ctrl = (VCCoreSubjects)board.InstantiateViewController("Number2VC");
        ctrl.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve;
        this.PresentViewController(ctrl, true, null);
    }
```

Here is the error code:

Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: Could not find a storyboard named 'Main.storyboard' in bundle NSBundle  (loaded)
Native stack trace:
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001108d829b __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001115f1735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   UIKitCore                           0x0000000117d625bb +[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:] + 676
    3   SixthFormFinder                     0x000000010336f4b9 xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 217
    4   ???                                 0x0000000134cc27bb 0x0 + 5180762043

Comment: The error is telling you that `MainStoryboard` does not exist, do you mean to be actually using `Main.storyboard` ? PS: Do NOT post errors are images, post the actual formatted error text directly into your question.

Comment: That sadly hasn't solved it, it's still coming up with the same error message

Comment: What is the name of the storyboard that is in your project?

Comment: Main.storyboard

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project and re-deploy/debug.

Comment: In what way should I clean/rebuild/re-deploy/debug?

Comment: Don’t worry, I’ve fixed it, it was the identifier I had in the second line that was also wrong. Thanks anyways